# What happens when a parent variable type stores a child object and invokes an overridden method?

Tags: c#, inheritance

What happens when a parent variable type stores a child object and invokes a method that was overridden by the child class?

Does the parent version of the method execute or does the child version of the method execute?

```
public class testa
{
    public virtual void display()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine('a');
    }
}

public class testb : testa
{
    public override void display()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine('b');
    }
}
```

then call somewhere

```
testa b = new testb();
b.display();
```

Through running this test on my own I found that it says "b", I would still like a formal answer though to  fully understand what is happening.

Comment: I'm unsure if you mean a simple inheritance where you hold a parent who was instantiated to a child, or something more interesting. If it's the second case, add some code or explain yourself better. If it's the first - read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table

Comment: @asafrob i added code, i'm not sure if this is what you thought it was or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to [Runtime polymorphism](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/kirtan007/runtime-polymorphism-in-C-Sharp/). When a `virtual method is called` on an object, then the `most derived version` of the method `gets called` always.

Like in your case, you are calling `display` (virtual) method which is overriden in `testb` class. Hence, it gets called to display `b`.

```
testa b = new testb();
b.display();
```

But however, if you are using `method hiding` using `new` keyword -

```
public class testa
{
    public void display()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine('a');
    }
}

public class testb : testa
{
    public new void display()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine('b');
    }
}
```

And you run this code -

```
testa b = new testb();
b.display();
```

You will see `a` gets print because `base class method gets called` as its `no more virtual`.

Refer to the link [Overriding VS Method Hiding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838553/overriding-vs-method-hiding) for more detailed explanation if its not clear yet.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a class that contains a virtual function you get something that is called a virtual table (or vtable)
The vtable holds pointers to all of the virtual functions in the class by address in the class.

When you hold a pointer to a parent class which is actually a derived class and call a virtual function, the vtable is accessed to get the address of the function, and runs the function in the actual derived type.

This is a big topic and you better read about is some more to learn things i haven't mentioned such as how object sizes are increased with a size of a pointer or where is the vtable actually saved

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table