# Questions about Abstract method and interface method

Tags: c#, .net, interface, abstract-class, abstract-methods

Hi all i have some doubts about abstract class and interface

### Am not asking about difference between interface and abstract class . Am just asking about different between abstract method and interface method

Abstract methods are same as interface methods . I know if we inherit the interface and abstract class in child class ,then we must implement the those side methods .But we can't implement the non abstract methods. So

> 1. my question is what is the different between abstract method and interface ?

and

> 2". another question is we can partially implement the Non-abstract methods in abstract class , Is it possible to partially implement the abstract method in abstract class ?

I also referred many sites , but does not one give the solution for second question

Question with code

Here is my abstract class and have one abstract method(xxx) and another one non abstract moethod(yyy) and interface method (xxx)

```
public abstract class AbstractRam
{
    public abstract int xxx();// What is the difference in interface method ?

    public int yyy()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}

public interface InterfaceRam
{
    int xxx();// What is the difference in abstract method ?


}
```

and i inherited the both in another class

```
public class OrdinaryClass : AbstractRam
{
    public OrdinaryClass()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }
    public override int xxx()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

public class OrdinaryClass2 : InterfaceRam
{
    public OrdinaryClass2()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }
    public int xxx()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Let see my  xxx method , Both methodes are working same , Not a big difference

> question :  Is it have any difference ? if is it same , then which one is the best way ?

Comment: What do you mean with _partially_ ?

Comment: This has been asked before, many times. So a new question must be much more specific.

Comment: Also, _"we can't implement the non abstract methods"_ is not really true.

Comment: @HenkHolterman hmm We can partially implement the non abstract method in parent(abstract) class and then we can fully implement that methods  in child class , Is it possible to abstract method ? understood ?

Comment: csc.exe: `MyMethod()` cannot declare a body because it is marked abstract. Abstract (or MustInherit in VB) methods cannot contain implementation. "Partially" implemented methods, or the use of the same, can be marked as `virtual` and be overridden in derived classes as long as the overridden method calls the base implementation.

Comment: @RameshRajendran - No, not understood.  We have partial methods (in partial classes) and default implementation (virtual methods) but nothing called "partial implementation". Do not make up your own terminology.

Comment: Just wait a mins , I will asking with code example's . Any one does not understand my question .

Comment: Hey why is it duplicate ? Read my question one another time .

Comment: Shouting won't help, start by fixing the title.

Comment: Okay let see .  abstract method and interface method are same or not ?

Comment: Okay all , See my updated question . Now i explained with code .

Comment: Yes, there are similarities, So we are back to interface vs abstract class, like in the linked dupe and many others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Interface methods are abstract methods. Yes they are the same as abstract methods in abstract classes as both are abstract. A caveat here though is how they are handled when polymorphism comes into play. This can be illustrated with the following code:

   ```
   interface IA 
   { 
       int xxx(); 
   }

   abstract class B 
   { 
       public abstract int yyy();
   }

   class C : B, IA
   {
       public int xxx()
       {
           return 1;
       }

       public int yyy()
       {
           return 1;
       }
   }
   ```

The `yyy` definition actually hides the abstract method in B and needs to be declared as `public override int yyy()...` to prevent this.

2. No. you cannot "partially implement the non-abstract methods in abstract class". You can partially implement an abstract class by providing some concrete methods and some abstract methods. You cannot "partially implement" an abstract method though. A method in an abstract class is either abstract or it isn't.
3. In your code example, `OrdinaryClass` is providing an implementation of `xxx`. `OrdinaryClass2` is hiding that abstract method though and providing its own `xxx`. as mentioned in (1). Please read up on method hiding in C# for more details, eg http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_polymorphism.html and [Overriding vs method hiding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838553/overriding-vs-method-hiding/3838692#3838692).

Comment: Okay . good . Now please see my question !!!

Comment: +1 for your oral explanation

Answer (score -1):

Finally I found the answer by my self .

- The big difference of abstract method and interface method is

> We can implement the abstract method in inside of the same abstract class , but we can't implement the interface method in inside of  the same interface .

Comment: You have just provided a "what's the difference between abstract classes and interfaces" answer to your question, which you claimed was not asking "what's the difference between abstract classes and interfaces?" I wrote pretty much the same words for you at the start and you complained that wasn't what you were asking for. Lost for words... :(