# Why does this C# code return what it does

Tags: c#, interface, code-snippets

Can someone please help me understand why this code snippet returns "Bar-Bar-Quux"? I'm having a hard time understanding this even after reading up on interfaces.

```
interface IFoo
{ 
    string GetName();
}

class Bar : IFoo
{
    public string GetName() { return "Bar"; }
}

class Baz : Bar
{
    public new string GetName() { return "Baz"; }
}

class Quux : Bar, IFoo
{
    public new string GetName() { return "Quux"; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Bar f1 = new Baz();
        IFoo f2 = new Baz();
        IFoo f3 = new Quux();
        Console.WriteLine(f1.GetName() + "-" + f2.GetName() + "-" + f3.GetName());
    }
}
```

Comment: @Rahul It's Bar-Bar-Quux on my end (VS 2013 on Win7).

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Why f1.GetName returns "Bar"? Why f2.GetName() returns Bar, or why f3.GetName() return Quux?  The first one should be obvious.  The 2nd one is a little tricky.  The 3rd one probably requires a close reading of the spec to know what will happen without just trying it (for me anyway)

Comment: @PeteBaughman, Yeah, my bad. didn't observe that `Baz` is not implementing `IFoo`. Removed comment.

Comment: @Rahul - `Baz` does implement `IFoo` through its inheritance of `Bar`.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I mean it's not explicitely implementing IFoo.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There are two things happening here. One is member hiding. This is fairly well-known and covered [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838553/overriding-vs-method-hiding). The other, less-known feature is interface re-implementation covered in section 13.4.6 of the C# 5 specification. To quote:

> A class that inherits an interface implementation is permitted to **re-implement** the interface by including it in the base class list. A re-implementation of an interface follows exactly the same interface mapping rules as an initial implementation of an interface. Thus, the inherited interface mapping has no effect whatsoever on the interface mapping established for the re-implementation of the interface.

and

> Inherited public member declarations and inherited explicit interface member declarations participate in the interface mapping process for re-implemented interfaces.

The result for `f1.GetName()` is "Bar" because the method `Baz.GetName` is hiding `Bar.GetName` and `f1` is declared as type `Bar`. There is no dispatch to the run-time type's implementation unless it is explicitly declared as virtual and overridden.

Similarly, for `f2.GetName()`, `Baz.GetName` is hiding the implementation in `Bar`, so it is not called when using dispatch through a reference to the interface. The interface is "mapped" to the method declared in `Bar` because that is the type on which the interface was declared. It does not matter that `Baz` has a compatible method with the same name. The rules for interface mapping are defined in section 13.4.4 of the spec. If `GetName` had been declared virtual in `Bar`, it could be overridden, which then would be called through the interface. The result is therefore also "Bar".

For `f3.GetName()`, `Quux` re-implements `IFoo` so it gets to define its own mapping to `GetName`. Note that it also hides the implementation inherited from `Bar`. It is not necessary to use new to do the re-implementation, it simply suppresses the warning about hiding. Therefore the result is "Quux".

So that explains the output that you see: "Bar-Bar-Quux"

This [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/12/08/so-many-interfaces-part-two.aspx) by Eric Lippert discuss some more nuances in this tricky feature.

Answer (score 8):

Interfaces by definition have no associated implementation, which is to say their methods are always virtual and abstract. In contrast, the class `Bar` above defines a concrete implementation for `GetName`. This satisfies the contract required to implement `IFoo`.

Class `Baz` now inherits from `Bar` and declares a `new` method `GetName`. That is to say that the parent class `Bar` has a method with the same name, but it is completely ignored when working with `Baz` objects explicitly.

However, if a `Baz` object is cast as a `Bar`, or simply assigned to a variable of type `Bar` or `IFoo`, it will do as it's told and behave like a `Bar`. In other words, the method name `GetName` refers to `Bar.GetName` instead of `Baz.GetName`.

Now, in the third case, `Quux` both inherits from `Bar` *and* implements `IFoo`. Now, when cast as an `IFoo` it will provide its own implementation (according to the specification provided in Mike Z's answer).

When a Quux is cast as a Bar, however, it returns "Bar", just as Baz does.

Answer (score 4):

The output is Bar-Bar-Quux as a result of 3 calls to GetName() in your Console.WriteLine method call.

```
Bar f1 = new Baz();
IFoo f2 = new Baz();
IFoo f3 = new Quux();
Console.WriteLine(f1.GetName() + "-" + f2.GetName() + "-" + f3.GetName());
//Bar-Bar-Quux
```

Let's examine each call so it can be made more clear what happens.

**f1.GetName()**

`f1` is instantiated as `Baz`. *However*, it is **typed** as `Bar`. Because `Bar` exposes `GetName`, when `f1.GetName()` is used, that is the method which is called - *regardless* of the fact that `Baz` also implements `GetName`. The reason is that `f1` is not typed as `Baz`, and if it were, it would call `Baz`'s `GetName` method. An example of that would be to examine the output of

```
Console.WriteLine(((Baz)f1).GetName() + "-" + f2.GetName() + "-" + f3.GetName());
//Baz-Bar-Quux
```

This is possible because of two facts. First, `f1` was initially instantiated as `Baz`, it was simply typed as `Bar`. Second, `Baz` *does* have a `GetName` method, and the use of `new` in its definition hides the inherited `Bar`'s `GetName` method allowing `Baz`'s `GetName` to be called.

**f2.GetName()**

A very similar typing is occurring with `f2`, which is defined as

```
IFoo f2 = new Baz();
```

While the Baz class does implement a `GetName` method, it does not implement `IFoo`'s `GetName` method because `Baz` does not inherit from `IFoo` and therefore the method is not available. `Bar` implements `IFoo`, and since `Baz` inherits from `Bar`, `Bar`'s `GetName` is the method which is exposed when `f2` is typed as `IFoo`.

Again, since `f2` was initially instantiated as `Baz`, it can still be cast to `Baz`.

```
Console.WriteLine(f1.GetName() + "-" + ((Baz)f2).GetName() + "-" + f3.GetName());
//Bar-Baz-Quux
```

And will have the same output result for the reason noted above for `f1` (`f2` was originally typed as `Baz`, and `Baz`'s `GetName` method hides the inherited `Bar`'s `GetName` method).

**f3.GetName()**

Different story here. `Quux` *does* inherit and implement `IFoo`, **and** it hides `Bar`'s implementation of `IFoo` by using `new`. The result is that `Quux`'s `GetName` method is the one which is called.