# Polymorphic nature of using Func<T> in C#

Tags: c#, polymorphism, func

I ran into a interesting issue last week and I am not sure I truly understand the polymorphic nature of the [following code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Guar24). I created this sample based some code that I wrote.

**Basic Setup**

- I have a class "Trainer" that knows how to train a animal.
- I use that as a base class and created a subclass "DogTrainer" that knows how to only train dogs.
- I created a function pointer using the superclass as the return type.
- I then call that function getting a new instance of the subclass "DogTrainer".
- I then call the "Train" method of the instance returned from the function pointer.
- The "Train" method invokes the "Trainer" - "Train" method not the "DogTrainer" - "Train" method as expected

Here is the code

```
// Does not work as expected
// Calls the Trainer Train not the DogTrainer Train
var getTrainer = new Func<Trainer>(() => new DogTrainer(new Dog()));
var funcTrainer = getTrainer();
Console.WriteLine(funcTrainer.Train());
```

Now if I use a Interface as the return type it does work as expected "IF" I have the interface directly marked on the "DogTrainer" subclass

```
// Works as expected 
var getITrainer = new Func<ITrainer>(() => new DogTrainer(new Dog()));
var funcITrainer = getITrainer();
Console.WriteLine(funcITrainer.Train());
```

If I do not have the interface on the subclass it does not work as expected. [See Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Guar24)

```
// Does not work as expected 
// Calls the Trainer Train not the Dog Trainer Train
var getITrainerWithNoInterface = new Func<ITrainer>(() => new DogTrainerWithNoInterface(new Dog()));
var funcITrainerWithNoInterface = getITrainerWithNoInterface();
Console.WriteLine(funcITrainerWithNoInterface.Train());
```

If someone could let me know what I am missing here, this behavior is not what I expected. When I discovered this bug in my code I was able to solve it, what I am looking for here is the "Why" this is happening.

Here is `DogTrainerWithNoInterface` which is likely the main part of the puzzle (`Trainer:ITrainer`)

```
public class DogTrainerWithNoInterface : Trainer
{
    public DogTrainerWithNoInterface(IAnimal animal)
        : base(animal)
    { }

    public new string Train()
    {
        return $"Speak Ubu, Speak : {Animal.Speak()}";
    }
}
```

Comment: You're seeing this behavior because of covariant generic types, not because of polymorphism

Comment: This is the behavior of "interface reimplementation" as it is called in the language specification. I described it in a similar example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25008171/517852). It is unrelated to `Func<T>` which only complicates matters unnecessarily here.

Comment: Thanks for effort puting the question together with good compact samples. As @mikez pointed out large part of the question has very nice answer alread (linked as duplicate). The first sample is covered by [What is shadowing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673779/what-is-shadowing).

Comment: Thanks for the information. I see what is going on now.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE: This answer is purely for describing the "new" issue due to not fitting in the comment. Please ignore voting as it doesn't fully answer his question.**

*Sample from OP's link:*

```
public class DogTrainer : Trainer, ITrainer
{
    public DogTrainer(IAnimal animal)
        : base(animal)
    { }

    public new string Train()
    {
        return $"Speak Ubu, Speak : {Animal.Speak()}";
    }
}
```

Do not use `new` when declaring methods/properties. Make them `virtual` on the base and then `override` them. What you are doing is hiding the method on your base.

You can only get your `new` method to invoke when working with that specific type (`DogTrainer`). Any down-casting to the base will invoke it's method i.e. working with a variable declared as `Trainer` or `ITrainer`.

[Knowing When to Use Override and New Keywords (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153.aspx)

Comment: Note that you answering almost opposite of what OP observed - second version (interface based) obviously successfully calls `DogTrainer.Train` and not the base one.

Comment: True. Guess I should note that. Way too much to fit in the comment block.