# Syntax for method hiding

Tags: swift

What is the syntax for method hiding in swift? I've tried a bunch of options in the playground, but keep getting errors. Haven't been able to find any documentation on it either.

In superclass:

```
func performFunction() {
     print("performing function...")
}
```

In subclass, tried a couple different options that do not seem to work

```
new func performFunction() {
   print("function...")
}
```

and

```
func new performFunction() {
   print("function...")
}
```

Comment: If you would've just started typing the method name, Xcode would've autocompleted the right syntax for you.

Comment: it keeps trying to autocorrect me to override the function, not hide it : (

Comment: is this not possible in Swift?

Comment: You can't decrease the visibility of a method, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Method hiding isn't possible in Swift, only overriding. Moreover, class methods (as implemented using the `static` keyword) are all final, so you can't even override at that level.

Comment: Method "hiding" doesn't make a lot of sense to me...

Comment: Thank you Nate Cook! Have to do an assignment later (implementing classes in Swift, one part of it using method hiding) and thought I was crazy. This would explain why there is zero documentation on it...

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `override` keyword:

```
class SubClass: ParentClass {
    override func performFunction() {
        println("function...")
    }
}
```

See [the Swift Programming Language: Inheritance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html) for more info.

Comment: thank you but i do not mean overriding. i am looking for method hiding. (they are different) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838553/overriding-vs-method-hiding

Answer (score 0):

Question answered thanks to Nate Cook!

"Method hiding isn't possible in Swift, only overriding. Moreover, class methods (as implemented using the static keyword) are all final, so you can't even override at that level."