# How do I call a function in a polymorphic object list?

Tags: c#, list, polymorphism

In C#, if I have an object that is inherited from another object, and I have a list of the inherited object, how can I call a function in the base class?

Here is an example:

```
class testObject
{
    public void testFunction()
    {

    }
}

class testObject2 : testObject
{
    public void testFunction()
    {

    }
}
```

Here is the list:

```
List<testObject> testObjects
```

If I add some `testObject2` objects to the list, how can I call the `testFunction` `function` for each `testObject2` object? If I try and call `testFunction` for each object, the `testFunction` in the `testObject` is called.

**EDIT**

When adding the override code to the `testFunction` in `testObject2`, I am getting this error:

> cannot override inherited member because it is not marked virtual,
>   abstract, or override

Comment: Change the function in `testObject2` to `public override void testFunction()`. What you have right now is hiding (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838553/overriding-vs-method-hiding), not overriding.

Comment: Can you please have a look at my edit?

Comment: Sorry - I forgot to add - you need to add the keyword `virtual` to the `testObject` method as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable polymorphic funtions you must declare the function as `virtual`, or `abstract` and then `override` them in child classes

```
class testObject
{
    public virtual void testFunction()
    {

    }
}

class testObject2 : testObject
{
    public override void testFunction()
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class testObject
{
    public virtual void testFunction()
    {

    }
}

class testObject2 : testObject
{
    public override void testFunction()
    {

    }
}
```

You need to add `virtual` to the method in testObject class and `override` it in the testObject2. If you want to add a little logic to already existing logic you can do it like this:

```
    public override void testFunction()
    {
         //it is calling the method in base
         base.testFunction();

        //here you can add more logic if you want.
    }
```

If you want totally separate method in which you do something else you just

```
    public override void testFunction()
    {
        //write another logic.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Class Definition:

```
class  testObject
    {
        public string s;
        public virtual void testFunction()
        {
            string b = s;
        }
    }

    class testObject2 : testObject
    {
        public string m;
        public override void testFunction()
        {
            string x = m;

        }
    }
```

Function call:

```
  List<testObject> testObjects = new List<testObject>();
  testObjects.Add(new testObject2() { m = "a" });
  testObjects[0].testFunction();
```