# Why override keyword produces error when no override produces warning and do overriding?

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding

The code below produces error and does not compile. But when we remove `override` keyword, it produces only warning, compiles and even does overriding.

Is there any logical explanation?

```
class Baseclass
{
    public void fun()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hi ");
    }

    public void fun(int i)
    {
        Console.Write("Hello ");
    }
}


class Derived : Baseclass
{
    public override void fun()
    {
        Console.Write("Bye ");
    }
}


class MyProgram
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Derived d;
        d = new Derived();
        d.fun();
        d.fun(77);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# you can only override method that is marked at virtual. Try this instead

```
class Baseclass
{
    public virtual void fun()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hi ");
    }
}


class Derived : Baseclass
{
    public override void fun()
    {
        Console.Write("Bye ");
    }
}
```

When you put `override` in function signatures, compile requires a matching virtual method (signatures and return type both) in base class that doesn't exists so an error is raised.

When you removes overrides keyword that actually hides method of `BaseClass` but doesn't overrides that. In this case compiler only raise warning and continues to compile.

There is a little difference between overriding and hiding See [Overriding vs method hiding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838553/overriding-vs-method-hiding) for more details

Comment: OK. So it works like the `new` keyword would be used but is not so the warining appears :) now I understand the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Well you need to put `new` keyword only if you want to hide the method. If you wanna override, mark the method in base class as virtual. Hiding the method will not show any polymorphic behavior.

Answer (score 0):

C# contains a keyword `virtual` which allows you to mark members to be overridden in derived classes.

The reason as stated in the documentation is:

> By default, methods are non-virtual. You cannot override a non-virtual method.

Why did the language designers do it this way where you have to explicitly state that a method can be overridden? I can't speak for them but it seems obvious they wanted to give programmers a safe way to avoid overriding members by mistake. That seems the most obvious win here.

So when designing a class you should mark classes you see as being usefully overridden as virtual.

You can read more on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx).

So you Baseclass will look like this:

```
class Baseclass
{
    public virtual void fun()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hi ");
    }

    public void fun(int i)
    {
        Console.Write("Hello ");
    }
}
```

Of course you could add `virtual` to the overloaded method taking an int as well.

Comment: It is clear and true what you said. But it is not the answear on the `Is there any logical explanation?` question about compiler behavioiur ;)

Comment: `You can read more on MSDN.` it is true fact about every question marked as C# related ;)