# Unity3D: Swapping child class instances (State pattern)

Tags: c#, oop, unity-game-engine, state

I created the following three scripts to test out the State pattern in Unity3D (I'm SUPER new to Unity) and got unexpected results:

BaseState

```
public class BaseState {
    public void Enter()
    {
        Debug.Log("Entered BaseState");
    }
}
```

IntroState

```
public class IntroState : BaseState {
    public void Enter()
    {
        Debug.Log("Entered IntroState");
    }
}
```

StateController

```
public class StateController : MonoBehavior {
    private BaseState state;

    void Start()
    {
        state = new IntroState();
        state.Enter();
    }
}
```

When I attach this to a GameObject, I expect to see "Entered IntroState" in the console. Instead, I see "Entered BaseState".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are "hiding" a method when you define it with the same signature in a subclass.
You should mark `BaseState.Enter` as  `public void virtual` and add `override` in `IntroState.Enter` so it becomes `public override void Enter()`

What is happening is that you have a `state` variable with a `BaseState` type. When you write `state = new IntroState();` you are doing *implicit upcasting* (google it up). After that you are calling an `Enter` method on a `BaseState` object, thats why you get "Entered BaseState"

I also recommend you checking out a library called "Stateless" and this answer for more information

[Overriding vs method hiding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838553/overriding-vs-method-hiding)