# Calling overriden method used on base type

Tags: c#, inheritance, char

In this code:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class TextInput
    {
        protected string _text = "";

        public void Add(char c)
        {
            _text += c;
        }

        public string GetValue()
        {
            return _text;
        }
    }


    public class NumericInput : TextInput
    {
        public new void Add(char c)
        {
            if (!char.IsDigit(c)) return;
            _text += c;
        }
    }


    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TextInput input = new NumericInput();
            input.Add('1');
            input.Add('a');
            input.Add('0');
            Console.WriteLine(input.GetValue());

            Console.WriteLine(char.IsDigit('1'));
            Console.WriteLine(char.IsDigit('a'));
            Console.WriteLine(char.IsDigit('0'));
        }
    }
}
```

... calling `Console.WriteLine(char.IsDigit('a'));` returns correctly `False` but in the overridden `Add` method it always return `True`.

Obviously it calls `TextInput.Add()` instead of `NumericInput.Add()`. Can this be corrected inside the overriden `Add()` method? Code in `Main` may not change!

Comment: Make `Add` virtual and override it with `override` keyword

Comment: @AleksAndreev Would that be the only possible option in this case?

Comment: Can you please explain us why you use new keyword? if you are trying to achieve method overriding. Second thing, here you are creating instance of base class `TextInput` and calling `Add()`, execution will not go into method present in derived class will not check `IsDigit()` condition. Please provide us some valid example

Comment: Here is output of your example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/J9Xjon

Comment: I think this answer will help a lot: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3838692/6300600

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the difference between new and override in c#. Plus, take a look at virtual key.

I'm not going to explain it now. There is a lot of information about this here and on the web.

MS docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/knowing-when-to-use-override-and-new-keywords

More info here: [Difference between new and override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399127/difference-between-new-and-override)

To sum up, use override in this case. Try them both and you'll realize how do they work.
There

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement method overriding, use `virtual` keyword in base class and `override` keyword in derived class.

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class TextInput
    {
        protected string _text = "";
        //Virtual allows derived class to enhance its functionality.
        public virtual void Add(char c)
        {
            _text += c;
        }
        ....
    }


    public class NumericInput : TextInput
    {
        //Override function will add more functionality to base class function
        public override void Add(char c)
        {
            if (!char.IsDigit(c)) return;
            _text += c;
        }
    }
```

Now `new` keyword does not override base class function, it will hide base class functionality.

If you want to override function in derived class, then use `override` instead of `new` keyword

For more reference, visit: [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838553/overriding-vs-method-hiding/3838692#3838692)

Comment: It's good and all but this isn't java, so no `@override` needed.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use abstract class:

since we have multiple `add` implementation and also can not use operators on `T`, declare it as abstract and implement on derived classes

```
public abstract class Input<T>
    {
        protected T __input;
        public abstract void Add(T c);
        public T GetValue()
        {
            return __input;
        }
    }
    public class NumericInput : Input<int>
    {
        public override void Add(int c)
        {
            __input += c;
        }
    }
    public class TextInput : Input<string>
    {
        public override void Add(string c)
        {
            __input += c;
        }
    }

static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var input = new NumericInput();
            input.Add(1);
            input.Add(2);
            Console.WriteLine(input.GetValue());

            var text = new TextInput();
            text.Add("a");
            text.Add("a");
            text.Add("a");
            Console.WriteLine(text.GetValue());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```