# Generic type parameter as type parameter and new a generic type in one of the function of C#

Tags: c#, generics, types, parameters

I want to implement a Priority Queue, with the ablity can specify the type of the queue(generic queue or unique queue).

```
public class PriorityQueue<TItem, TKey, TQueue> : IEnumerable<TItem>
    where TKey : IComparable
    where TQueue : Queue<TItem>, new ()
{
    private readonly Func<TItem, TKey> _keySelector;

    private readonly SortedDictionary<TKey, TQueue> _data = new SortedDictionary<TKey, TQueue>();

    public PriorityQueue(Func<TItem, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        _keySelector = keySelector;
    }

    public void Enqueue(TItem item)
    {
        var key = _keySelector(item);

        if (!_data.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            _data.Add(key, new TQueue());
        }

        var queue = _data[key];
        queue.Enqueue(item);
    }

    public TItem Dequeue()
    {
        if (IsEmpty)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Queue is EMPTY");
        }

        var key = _data.Keys.First();
        var queue = _data[key];

        var item = queue.Dequeue();
        if (queue.Count == 0)
        {
            _data.Remove(key);
        }

        return item;
    }

    public bool IsEmpty => _data.Count == 0;

    private int Count
    {
        get
        {
            var count = 0;
            foreach (var key in _data.Keys)
            {
                count += _data[key].Count;
            }

            return count;
        }
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _data.Clear();
    }


    public IEnumerator<TItem> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new Enumerator(_data);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    private class Enumerator : IEnumerator<TItem>
    {
        private readonly SortedDictionary<TKey, TQueue> _dictionary;
        private readonly int _dictionaryCount;
        private int _currentPosition;

        public Enumerator(SortedDictionary<TKey, TQueue> data)
        {
            _dictionary = data;
            _dictionaryCount = DictionaryCount;
            _currentPosition = 0;
            Current = default(TItem);
        }

        private int DictionaryCount
        {
            get
            {
                var count = 0;
                foreach (var key in _dictionary.Keys)
                {
                    count += _dictionary[key].Count;
                }

                return count;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {

        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            if (_currentPosition >= _dictionaryCount)
            {
                return false;
            }

            Current = GetCurrent();
            _currentPosition++;

            return true;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            _currentPosition = 0;
        }

        public TItem Current { get; private set; }

        private TItem GetCurrent()
        {
            var sum = 0;
            var item = default(TItem);

            foreach (var key in _dictionary.Keys)
            {
                var queue = _dictionary[key];

                sum += queue.Count;

                if (sum > _currentPosition)
                {
                    item = queue.Take(queue.Count - (sum - _currentPosition) + 1).Last();
                    break;
                }
            }

            return item;
        }

        object IEnumerator.Current => Current;
    }
}
```

and the unique queue

```
public class UniqueQueue<T> : Queue<T>
{
    private HashSet<T> _hashSet;

    public UniqueQueue()
    {
        _hashSet = new HashSet<T>();
    }

    public new void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        if (_hashSet.Add(item))
        {
            base.Enqueue(item);
        }
    }

    public new T Dequeue()
    {
        var item = base.Dequeue();
        _hashSet.Remove(item);
        return item;
    }

    public new void Clear()
    {
        _hashSet.Clear();
        base.Clear();
    }
}
```

But in the unit test, it fails with the following code

```
       [TestMethod]
    public void TestPriorityUniqueQueue()
    {
        var puq = new PriorityQueue<Node, int, UniqueQueue<Node>>(node => node.Key);

        var node1 = new Node(1, "One");
        var node2 = new Node(2, "Two");
        var node3 = new Node(1, "One 1");

        puq.Enqueue(node1);
        puq.Enqueue(node1);
        puq.Enqueue(node1);
        puq.Enqueue(node2);
        puq.Enqueue(node3);

        var list = new List<Node>();
        foreach (var node in puq)
        {
            list.Add(node);
        }

        Assert.AreEqual(list[0], node1);
        **Assert.AreEqual(list[1], node3);**
        Assert.AreEqual(list[2], node2);

        puq.Dequeue();
        puq.Dequeue();
        puq.Dequeue();

        Assert.IsTrue(puq.IsEmpty);
    }
```

I debug the test case and find when call the puq.Enqueue(node1), it calls the Enqueue() function from Queue, not my UniqueueQueue. But when I debug, I find that in the Enqueue of PriorityQueue, the variable is type of UniqueQueue, but it not call the Enqueue() of UniqueQueue. I really want to know why, or give me some advise about how this possible?

It fails in the bold line and the stack trace is

> Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:. Actual:. 
>      in ToolsTests.PriorityQueueTest.TestPriorityUniqueQueue() position somefolder\ToolsTests\PriorityQueueTests.cs:line number 118

[the debug info of the queue variable from PriorityQueue<>.Enqueue() methord](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjfF2.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you provide the line on which it failed and the stack trace as well as the error message. It will help people understand your issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overriding vs method hiding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838553/overriding-vs-method-hiding)

Comment: Thanks Dragonthoughts, it fails in the third part code, the line Assert.AreEqual(list[1], node3); and the stack trace has nothing helpful

Comment: Thanks dymanoid, I know the hiding rule. I was confused that when I new the TQueue in PriorityQueue's Enqueue() function, the TQueue should be UniqueueQueue, not Queue<Node>, it should call the Enqueue() of UniqueueQueue. So I think the problem is something of generic type parameter  that I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your generic type parameter `TQueue<T>` is expected to be of the type `Queue<T>` because you defined it in the generic constraint of the `PriorityQueue`:

```
 where TQueue : Queue<TItem>, new ()
```

Now whenever your code passes:

```
_data.Add(key, new TQueue());
```

It will create an instance of `Queue<T>` and not `UniqueQueue<T>`, hence it will never reach the `Enqueue` method of your `UniqueQueue<T>` as it calls the `Enqueue` method of `Queue<T>`.

Reasoning for this is because of the generic constraint (first code block above) you've supplied. It simply does not know the `UniqueQueue<T>` type, but rather the `Queue<T>` type, since that is what the `PriorityQueue<TItem, TKey, TQueue>` expects (because you 'told' him so). So whenever `new TQueue()` is executed, a new `Queue<T>` object will instantiated instead of `UniqueQueue<T>`.

In order for your tests to pass, and the `PriorityQueue<TItem, TKey, TQueue>` to actually use the `UniqueQueue<T>`, you must explicitly specify that you want to use the `UniqueQueue<T>` in the generic constraint:

```
where TQueue : UniqueQueue<TItem>, new()
```

Comment: Oh, I see it. I pay attention on the debug info, when I print the queue variable in PriorityQueue<>.Enqueue() methord with `Debug.WriteLine(queue.GetType());`, it shows `CRSCD.ITP.Tools.UniqueQueue`1[CRSCD.ITP.ToolsTests.Node]`, but the decaration of the queue variable should be Queue<TItem>, so it calls the Queue<TItem>.Enqueue(). Thanks a lot Jevgeni.