# C# polymorphism - upcasting

Tags: c#, .net-core

I would like to ask you for an explanation of this example:

```
public class A : B
{
    public override void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A");
    }
}

public class B
{
    public virtual void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B");
    }
}
```

Equation:

```
void Main()
{
    B b = (B)new A();

    b.Method(); // result A
}
```

Why upcasting did not work in this case?

Comment: Casting is a compile time concept; the runtime object is still an instance of `A`.

Comment: did you tried B b= new B(); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/object-oriented/polymorphism) say:

> If you want your derived class to have a member with the same name as a member in a base class, you can use the new keyword to hide the base class member. The new keyword is put before the return type of a class member that is being replaced. The following code provides an example:

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that method hiding is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838553/overriding-vs-method-hiding